# using php to "send me an email"

Tags: php, apache

I have a php file that handles contacting me from my site via email. I don't know much about php but when i use node all i have to do is start up my node server file and the whole site launches. My front end is html/javascript and the only "backend" is the contact_me.php. I need to be able to have my php running so that it works with my site. I know nothing about apache. If you could tell me how to setup what i need to setup or point me in the right direction that would be awesome. I have tried reading the documentation for apache to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

PHP mail [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) will help you set up mail in php.

If you are new to this, its better to use some inbuilt libraries like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which have decent enough documentation for beginners.

Comment: In php manual is there information about how to setup and configure apache? Also would PHPMailer require me to setup apache? The code actually works (well theoretically in the right environment). Its just the web server part that is not configured...